# Powershell function with two argument give takes one argument

Tags: function, powershell, powershell-2.0

I define the powershell function as below

```
function t ($a , $b ) {
    write-Host '1-', $a
    write-Host '2-', $b
}
```

When calling `t(4,5)` give

```
1- 4 5
2-
```

instead of natural

```
1- 4
2- 5
```

How can I get the second?

Comment: PowerShell separates function arguments with spaces, not commas.  look at the gotcha here http://stackoverflow.com/tags/powershell/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kayasax has answered the question in his comment.  Function calls do not require parens around the argument(s).

call with

```
t 4 5
```

instead of what you did.